# Marvel Comics BASIC games from the 1980s?

Tags: basic, identify-this-game

When I was a young kid in the mid-1980s, I attended a computer camp intended to introduce kids to BASIC.  One of the things we typically did was to transcribe BASIC programs from paper copies.  I remember there being a set of paper sheets that had games with Marvel Comics themes.  I believe that the sheets had some black-and-white Marvel Comics artwork alongside the corresponding BASIC program.  One program I remember was a Captain America action game where the player was Captain America riding on a motorcycle (I think represented as a `!`) that was traveling vertically up(?) the screen.  The player tried to steer left or right to try to navigate through a hole in a wall.  I think the game got progressively harder by making the hole smaller and smaller.  I think it looked something like:

```
***     **********





           !
```

I don't remember what machines (possibly IBM XTs?) or which implementation of BASIC we used.  The camp was in Massachusetts (which raises the possibility that it was run by Wang or Digital).

I suppose it's possible that these sheets were not licensed nor mass-produced and that someone at the camp made them themselves, although that wasn't my impression at the time.

Does anyone have any more information on those BASIC programs and perhaps know where I could still find them?

Comment: It might help others to identify if you add details like in what country and state this camp was, maybe even what camp. Likewise the computers used, etc.

Comment: @Raffzahn I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those BASIC programs probably came from a book called "Marvel Super Heroes Computer Fun".

Here you can find some photos of it:

https://blog.paxholley.net/2011/08/17/learning-basic-with-the-marvel-super-heroes/

I don't think the book is available nowadays but is probably easy to find on eBay.

Edit: it seems they were 2 books and are referenced on Amazon, but not available right now).

[https://www.amazon.com/Marvel-Super-Heroes-Computer-Book/dp/0917657055](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0917657055)

Comment: Yes, this is definitely it.  The specific program I mentioned is "Crasher"/"Menace of the Gray Gargoyle".  The whole book is available at https://archive.org/details/marvel-super-heroes-computer-fun-2/page/n15/mode/1up

Comment: And for completeness, https://archive.org/details/marvel-super-heroes-computer-fun-1/ for book 1.